RMO 2024 problem 2 regarding sum of remainders.
Yesterday the following problem appeared in RMO 2024:
$\textbf{Problem:}$ Let $R(n)$ be the sum of remainders when $n$ is divided by ${1,2,3,....n-1,n}$. For example, $R(7)=8$. Find all $n \in N$ such that $R(n)=n-1$.
$\textbf{My work:}$ I first found an explicit formula for $R(n)$ by means of the following recursion:
$\textit{Claim:}$ $R(n+1)-R(n)=2n+1-\sigma(n+1)$
where $\sigma(n)$ denotes the sum of divisors of n.
$\textit{Proof}:$ To prove this, consider $(n+1)\bmod(i)-n\bmod(i)$. This equals $1$, if $i$ does not divide $n+1$ and $1-i$ otherwise.
Summing this gives us the recursion.
After this it is not difficult to come up with the formula:
$$R(n)=n^2-(\sigma(1)+\sigma(2)+...\sigma(n)).$$
At this point I was stuck and decided to abandon the solution. I just want to know  if and how the solution can be continued from this point onwards.
Thanks.
PS: The (un)official considered remainders by $n/2,n/2+1.....n-1$ to get a quadratic lower bound on $R(n)$ and then bounded the values of $n$, to get the only solutions as $n=1$ or $n=5$.
PPS. The problem could also have been stated in the way:
$\textbf{Problem:}$Find all $n \in N$ such that $$\sigma(1)+\sigma(2)+\sigma(3)....+\sigma(n)=n^2-n+1$$
I think this (isolated ) problem may be solved using other techniques, but I am stuck here. SO in essence  my question is how to solve this. I am not able to come up with some kind of bound for the sum.

R(7)=0+1+1+3+2+1+0=8. 7 gives remainder 0 with1,1 with2,1 with3,3 with 4 etc...

My bad, I misinterpreted what a remainder is.  Previous comment deleted.

I edited the title to "remainders", because the original contest problem involves remainders, not divisors.

@tensorman666 the summation $\sigma(1)+\sigma(2)+...\sigma(n)$ obtained by you can be only bound in a manner similar to Sahaj's answer, and hence must end with ideas similar to the solutions on the internet. I don't think more than 4 marks are possible for this.

@DS thanks, the first thought that came into my mind while solving the problem was this and I had 10 minutes left so I did what I could

Where can one see these problems?

@calculatormathematical  ust search "RMO 2024 problems" on google

You can write $S = \sum_{r=1}^n \sigma(r) = \sum_{r=1}^n r \left\lfloor \frac{n}{r}\right\rfloor$*. This form is easier to bound to me atleast thereby possibly allowing a finite range of $n$ to check. Note that $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{\frac{n}2 + k}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{2n}{n + 2k}\right\rfloor$ for $0<k\le\frac{n}2$ is just $=1$ since $n<n+2k \le 2n$ gives $1\le \frac{2n}{2n+k}<2$. This makes $n/2$ particularly useful. Let us denote $h = \left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$. We have that $$\underbrace{\sum_{r=1}^{h} r\lfloor n/r\rfloor}_{S_1} + \underbrace{\sum_{r=h + 1}^n r\lfloor n/r\rfloor}_{S_2} = S$$
However $S_2$ is straightforward to evaluate because the floor part is just $1$; one can also bound $S_1$ trivially since $\lfloor n/r\rfloor \le n/r$ so that $S_1\le nh \le n^2/2$.
Thus $$\frac{n^2}2 + \color{blue}{\left(\sum_{r=n/2 + 1}^{n} r \right)} \geq S_1 + S_2 = S$$
This gives $$\frac{n^2}2 + \color{blue}{\frac18n(3n+2)}\geq n^2-n+1 \iff \frac18(7n^2+2n)\geq n^2-n+1 \iff n^2-10n+8\le 0$$
Over the integers this inequality has solutions $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Checking all of them one gets the solutions $n\in \{1,5\}$.
Note regarding * for showing the equality: evaluate $R(n)$ using $n = r\lfloor n/r\rfloor + (n\bmod r)$ directly from the question itself.

Yes, so in a sense the bounding idea was similar. Thank you! I wrote the claim originally presented in the post, do you think I can get any marks for that?

I don't think you can go too far without using a bounding technique. I dont think the equation can be solved in an "analytical method". As per marks for the claim: I am not sure honestly. It was my first time giving this exam yesterday.

For integers $n$ and $k$ with $0<k<n$, let $r_k(n)$ denote the remainder of $n$ divided by $k$, so that
$$R(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r_k(n).$$
Of course $r_k(n)\geq0$ for all such $k$ and $n$, and for $k>\tfrac n2$ we have $r_k(n)=n-k$. Let $k_0$ be the smallest integer greater than $\tfrac n2$. Then we readily find that
\begin{eqnarray}
R(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r_k(n)
&\geq&\sum_{k=k_0}^{n-1}r_k(n)
=\sum_{k=k_0}^{n-1}(n-k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-k_0-1}k=\frac12(n-k_0-1)(n-k_0),\\
\end{eqnarray}
where of course $n-k_0\geq\tfrac n2-1$. So if $R(n)=n-1$ then also
$$n-1\geq\tfrac12(n-k_0-1)(n-k_0)\geq\tfrac12(\tfrac n2-2)(\tfrac n2-1)=\tfrac18n^2-\tfrac34n+1,$$
and so we readily see that $n\leq7+\sqrt{33}<13$. From here it is a routine check for these small values of $n$ to find that only $n=1$ and $n=5$ work.

I already knew this(unofficial solution).The problem was to extend my line of thought, and/or provide any other solution.Thanks anyways tho, appreciate it

Side note: We can simplify this significantly. For $n \geq6$, Consider the remainders when divided by $k_0, k_0 + 1, k_0 + 2$. These are at least $k_0 - 1, k_0  - 2, k_0 - 3$.   Then, we want $3k_0 - 6  \geq n$, which is satisfied when $k_0 \geq 6$ or $ n \geq 12$. $\quad$ This quick bound is already small enough to check cases. Possible modifications are 1/ Split $n$ odd/even if desired, 2/ Start with $n \geq 4$ and use $4k_0 - 10 \geq n \Rightarrow n \geq 10$.
